# Getting fetch to retrieve content?

Tags: javascript, html, express, fetch

So I threw together this quick Express application that looks like so:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/content/1/", (req, res) =>
  res.send("Thinking about taking out a new loan? Call us today.")
);

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```

And inside Codepen I tried to fetch the string passed in `res.send()` and get it to render in the DOM like so:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/content/1/').then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
  document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = json.content;
});
```

If I paste that url directly into the browser I can see the string, but it does not render in the screen of Codepen and yes I have created a div element like so:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you try console.log(json.data), if you are getting the string before setting in div?

Comment: Does codepen.io connects to localhost servers as well?? I didn't know that....I also tried now but it didn't connect, it throws an error saying "Failed to fetch".....I dnt think codepen will able to fetch from local server

Comment: @RohitAmbre, it does once you include the `cors` library into the Express server, it works now, but to your point, the issue was a CORS error, again, resolved by just implementing `cors` library into Express server.

Comment: Does the answer below help you? Or you're having other issues?

Comment: @Daniel, that's interesting.....cool thanx

Answer (score 0):

You are returning text not JSON, so you should parse it as text:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/content/1/').then(res => res.text()).then(text => {
  document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = text;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues at play here:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const port = 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get("/content/1/", (req, res) =>
  res.json({ content: "Thinking about taking out a new loan? Call us today." })
);
```

1. CORS error which was solved by installing `cors` library into Express server and
2. The express router was doing a `res.send()` instead of `res.json()`.